# Lagging 1 year in xts object with weekly frequency

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to lag an xts dataset by 1 year. The data has weekly frequency, and I am currently using `lag.xts` function like so:

```
lag.xts(my_data, 52)
```

The problem is not all years have 52 weeks (some have 53). Is there a way I can take this into account somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to find the date which is closest to the specified date, minus a year?

This does the equivalent, but for a dataframe of values:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(x = rnorm(100), 
               dates = seq(as.Date("2015-12-27"), length = 100, by = "weeks"))

find_closest_day <- function(t) {
    ty = t - years(1)
    t52 = abs((t - weeks(52)) - ty)
    t53 = abs((t - weeks(53)) - ty)
    if (t52 < t53) {
        return(t - weeks(52))
    } else {
        return(t - weeks(53))
    }
}
find_closest_day<- Vectorize(find_closest_day)

data %>% 
  mutate(lagged_monday = as.Date(find_closest_day(dates))) %>%
  left_join(data, by = c("lagged_monday" = "dates"))

       x.x dates      lagged_monday   x.y
     <dbl> <date>     <date>        <dbl>
 1 -0.0768 2015-12-27 2014-12-28       NA
 2 -0.711  2016-01-03 2015-01-04       NA
 3 -1.94   2016-01-10 2015-01-11       NA
 4  0.584  2016-01-17 2015-01-18       NA
 5 -0.266  2016-01-24 2015-01-25       NA
 6 -1.04   2016-01-31 2015-02-01       NA
 7 -0.954  2016-02-07 2015-02-08       NA
 8 -0.809  2016-02-14 2015-02-15       NA
 9  0.458  2016-02-21 2015-02-22       NA
10  0.367  2016-02-28 2015-03-01       NA
# ℹ 90 more rows
```

Comment: +1 Nice approach! I was looking for something more "out-of-the-box", but this is helpful. Accepting this answer as it gets the job done nicely.

Comment: @umbe1987 I really wanted to do it with timeseries, but that isn't my expertise. Hopefully someone comes along who has more experience with those who is able to answer your question more fully

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative solution that converts to tibble and then back to xts.

#### Helper to convert xts to tibble.

```
xts_as_tibble <- function(x, name = "time", value = "value", group = "group"){
  time <- attr(x, "index")
  if ("POSIXt" %in% attr(time, "tclass")){
    if (!is.null(attr(time, "tzone"))){
      time <- lubridate::as_datetime(time,
                                     tz = attr(time, "tzone"))
    } else {
      time <- lubridate::as_datetime(time)
    }
  } else if ("Date" %in% attr(time, "tclass")){
    time <- lubridate::as_date(time)
  } else {
    time <- as.numeric(time)
  }
  ncol <- ncol(x)
  groups <- rep(colnames(x), each = length(time))
  if (is.null(groups)){
    groups <- rep(seq_len(ncol), each = length(time))
  }
  time <- rep(time, times = ncol)
  dplyr::tibble(!!group := groups,
                !!name := time,
                !!value := as.vector(x))
}
```

#### Calculation

```
library(tidyverse)
res <- my_data %>%
  xts_as_tibble() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = value) %>%
  mutate(across(-time, ~ if_else(time >= min(time) + years(1), .x, NA)))
my_data_lag <- xts(select(res, -time), order.by = res$time)
```